# How to download list of files from a file server?

Tags: download, apache-http-server, wget

How would I download a list of files from a file server like this one http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/ ?

I suppose I could use wget but then it tries to get all the links and the html file as well. Is there a better tool to accomplish this?

Comment: just to clarify your question: you just want the list of files which could be downloaded from the server, not the files itself (yet)?

Comment: In what way is a command like ` wget --no-verbose --spider --no-directories --recursive --level=2  http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/` not working for you?  If you could be more specific that might help

Answer (score 13):

You can specify what file extensions `wget` will download when crawling pages:

```
wget -r -A zip,rpm,tar.gz www.site.com/startpage.html
```

this will perform a recursive search and only download files with the `.zip`, `.rpm`, and `.tar.gz` extensions.

Answer (score 8):

supposing you really just want a list of the files on the server without fetching them (yet):

> %> wget -r -np --spider http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/ 2>&1 | awk -f filter.awk | uniq

while 'filter.awk' looks like this

```
/^--.*--  http:\/\/.*[^\/]$/ { u=$3; }
/^Length: [[:digit:]]+/ { print u; }
```

then you possibly have to filter out some entries like

```
"http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/?C=N;O=D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref: http://blog.incognitech.in/download-files-from-apache-server-listing-directory/

You can use following command:

```
wget --execute="robots = off" --mirror --convert-links --no-parent --wait=5 <website-url>
```

#### Explanation with each options

- `wget`: Simple Command to make CURL request and download remote files to our local machine.
- `--execute="robots = off"`: This will ignore robots.txt file while crawling through pages. It is helpful if you're not getting all of the files.
- `--mirror`: This option will basically mirror the directory structure for the given URL. It's a shortcut for `-N -r -l inf --no-remove-listing` which means:

  - `-N`: don't re-retrieve files unless newer than local
  - `-r`: specify recursive download
  - `-l inf`: maximum recursion depth (inf or 0 for infinite)
  - `--no-remove-listing`: don't remove '.listing' files
- `--convert-links`: make links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to local files
- `--no-parent`: don't ascend to the parent directory
- `--wait=5`: wait 5 seconds between retrievals. So that we don't thrash the server.
- `<website-url>`: This is the website url from where to download the files.

Happy Downloading :smiley: