# Possible to catch URLs in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, http, url

There is a great program for windows (URL Snooper: http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/urlsnooper/index.html) that allows you to view all URLs being requested on the machine.

Does any such program exist in linux (preferably command line)

Comment: im not sure what is that you are trying to do here.

Comment: Actually, it seems that URL Snooper does not **only** apply to *URLs being requested on the machine*, but **also** to URLs hidden in the HTML source of some page, which are not necessarily requested yet. For the latter see also "How to download list of files from a file server?" at http://superuser.com/questions/47089/wget-download-list-of-files-on-file-server

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that URL Snooper does not only apply to *URLs being requested on the machine*, but also to URLs hidden in the HTML source of some page, which are not necessarily requested yet. For the latter see also "[How to download list of files from a file server?](https://superuser.com/questions/47089/wget-download-list-of-files-on-file-server)" here at Super User. Or, in Firefox see menu Tools » Page Info » Media, or use add-ons like [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3006) or [UnPlug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2254). The following applies to seeing all URLs that are actually requested.

The command line [`ngrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ngrep) could do it, but gives far more details then you'd probably want.

Like: it will not simply show you the URL as typed into the location bar of a browser, but the whole HTTP request. (So: the IP address as resolved by the browser before actually making the request, and then the HTTP request the browser sends to that IP address.) And: it will also show this for every image etcetera used in the resulting page.

You might need to install `ngrep`, like on a default installation of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ngrep
```

To capture all HTTP GET requests to port 80:

```
sudo ngrep -W byline -qilw 'get' tcp dst port 80
```

Still, that would show you the whole request. (Try for yourself, if you're a Super User!) To limit that output some more to show only lines with `->`, `get` or `host`:

```
sudo ngrep -W byline -qilw 'get' tcp dst port 80 \
  | grep -i " -> \|get\|host"
```

Or, to capture all requests to port 80, but ignore those with the `Referer` header set (as set when requesting embedded images etcetera, but *also* set when clicking a link in a web page, thus *only* showing requests that are typed into a browser's location bar directly, or are opened in a new window, or are opened from a bookmark or email):

```
sudo ngrep -W byline -qilwv 'referer' tcp dst port 80 \
  | grep -i " -> \|get\|host"
```

Also sniffer tools like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html) have command line options. And, just as an aside and far more more basic, [`tcpdump`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump) is installed on most Linux distributions:

```
sudo tcpdump -Alfq -s 1024 \
  'tcp dst port 80 and ip[2:2] > 40 and tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-push != 0' \
  | grep -i " > \|get\|host"
```

Answer (score 4):

I can also recommend [url-sniff](http://pawilcz.eu/url-sniff/url-sniff.html) by Pawel Pawilcz. It is a lightweight Perl script that wraps nicely around `ngrep`. It supports colorized output as well. [Here](http://pawilcz.eu/url-sniff/colored.PNG) you will find a screenshot. It gives you a simple interface for sniffing all requested URLs.

Comment: The url-sniff website is offline, but there is a copy in the [archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20100618052519/http://pawilcz.eu/url-sniff/url-sniff.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an HTTP proxy such as [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/), but you'll have to configure your browser to use it - it doesn't snoop network traffic. It makes a log of URLs accessed which you can view with a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run a proxy that logs the requests as suggested by navilon. You don't need to configure anything on client side if you go for a transparent proxy.
2. Run a sniffer on the gateway.