# How to list all files/images in a website

Tags: website

Say given a url http://www.mysite.com/images/ , is there any tools can list all files or images under that directory? If the web server doesn't forbid list directory (afair, some old version apache server default value is allowing listing). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'[wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)' is the tool of choice, use the answers of ['wget-download-list-of-files-on-file-server'](https://superuser.com/questions/47089/wget-download-list-of-files-on-file-server)

Answer (score 1):

it'll be related to types of web server ( Apache, Zope , etc )

I think you mean like that ,

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

To get that kind of access, the host need to set up in the Apache/Config (if web server is Apache)

Retrieving all lists of directories/files/images is just browsing via Web Browser.

There's another way.

if you have ftp, sftp or ssh access to the web server, you can easily list the files in the directory of a remote server.

```
cd ~/images 
ls
```

Still using FTP (if you have access) is okay.

Cheers.